# FaunaDB search document and get its ranking based on a score

Tags: go, faunadb

I have the following Collection of documents with structure:

```golang
type Streak struct {
    UserID    string    `fauna:"user_id"`
    Username  string    `fauna:"username"`
    Count     int       `fauna:"count"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `fauna:"updated_at"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `fauna:"created_at"`
}
```

This looks like the following in FaunaDB Collections:

```json
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("streaks"), "288597420809388544"),
  "ts": 1611486798180000,
  "data": {
    "count": 1,
    "updated_at": Time("2021-01-24T11:13:17.859483176Z"),
    "user_id": "276989300",
    "username": "yodanparry"
  }
}
```

Basically I need a lambda or a function that takes in a `user_id` and spits out its **rank** within the collection. **rank** is simply sorted by the `count` field. For example, let's say I have the following documents (I ignored other fields for simplicity):

| user_id | count |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 12 |
| xyz | 10 |
| fgh | 999 |

If I throw in `fgh` as an input for this lambda function, I want it to spit out 1 (or 0 if you start counting from 0).

I already have an index for `user_id` so I can query and match a document reference from this index. I also have an index `sorted_count` that sorts document based on `count` field ascendingly.

My current solution was to query all documents by `sorted_count` index, then get the rank by iterating through the array. I think there should be a better solution for this. I'm just not seeing it.

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting things in Fauna isn't as easy as one might expect. But you might still be able to do something more efficient than you describe.

Assuming you have:

```
CreateIndex(
  {
    name: "sorted_count",
    source: Collection("streaks"),
    values: [
      { field: ["data", "count"] }
    ]
  }
)
```

Then you can query this index like so:

```
Count(
  Paginate(
    Match(Index("sorted_count")),
    { after: 10, size: 100000 }
  )
)
```

Which will return an object like this one:

```
{
  before: [10],
  data: [123]
}
```

Which tells you that there are 123 documents with `count` >= 10, which I think is what you want.

This means that, in order to get a user's rank based on their `user_id`, you'll need to implement this two-step process:

1. Determine the `count` of the user in question using your index on `user_id`.
2. Query `sorted_count` using the user's `count` as described above.

Note that, in case your collection has more than 100,000 documents, you'll need your Go code to iterate through all the pages based on the returned object's `after` field. 100,000 is Fauna's maximum allowed page size. See [the Fauna docs on pagination](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/tutorials/indexes/pagination.html) for details.

Also note that this might not reflect whatever your desired logic is for resolving ties.